# regex on a string from a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 "\n \t\tmain\\\\dah\n \t\t"
```

I have the string above, which is taken from a text box and put in a div. Except the string in the text box was `main\\dah` so how can I remove the other characters so it just returns `main\\dah`

thanks in advance

Comment: That _String_ looks like it was indented; simply `.trim()` it (polyfill may be required for old browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#somediv").html($.trim($("#somefield").val()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace unwanted characters using string replace.

```
var string = "\n \t\tmain\\\\dah\n \t\t";
var required = string.replace( /\s+/, '' );
```

You can have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8Lvo1eo/)

Comment: Intended behaviour is probably closer to `/^\s+|\s+$/g`